# colour cell in datagridview performance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to color the particular cell in DataGridView. I tried to do but it doesn't work.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

but for whole column it works...

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Then I tried the below code and it **DID** work but the performance of the datagridview is very slow when it comes to 2k rows. would it be possible to make performance better or anything other way to color particular cell in datagridview. thanks!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle MakeItRed = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    MakeItRed.BackColor = Color.Red;

    //make a whole column red
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle = MakeItRed;

    //make a specific cell red
    DataGridViewRow row2 = dataGridView1.Rows[2];
    row2.Cells[2].Style = MakeItRed;
}
```

Comment: Is it wise to have 2k rows in a grid when the user can only see ~50 at the same time? Apart from the performance problem becoming apparent now, it's not very efficient in the first place.

Comment: The one line at the top (`dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;`)  __should__ work. It does here. Where, when and how did you call it? (Assuming that the problem is not your varying column indexes..)

Comment: Did you call `dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;` and `dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;` in the `Form` constructor?  If so, the changes to rows / individual cells will fail because the `Form` and `DataGridView` are not yet visible.  The call should work fine if done anytime later, as in your solution of `DataGridView.CellFormatting`.  Try calling it in `Form.Load`.